# Bootstrap-3 carousel controls on outside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

See my [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/owKdCnv6Bo)

I have a Bootstrap-3 carousel with 3 x DIVs showing each time. You can click right and left for next 3 x DIVs to show. But my indicators are a whole area where you can click, the grey block. Is it possible to just have the > thingie clickable?
Also, how to get the > thingie to be outside my DIV, now its overlapping with my content? Gracias!

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id=
"carousel-example- generic">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target=
        "#carousel-example-generic"></li>

        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>

        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
    </ol><!-- Slider Content (Wrapper for slides )-->

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <p>
             aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
                <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <p>cccccccccccccc</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <p>dddddddddddddd</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
                <p>eeeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <p>ffffffffffffff</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href=
"#carousel-example-generic"><span class=
"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class=
"right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href=
"#carousel-example-generic"><span class=
"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators li { visibility: hidden; }

.carousel-inner .item {
font-size:10px;
color:#0404B4
}

.carousel-control {
z-index: 10;
top: 2%;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Please try to show a [minimally complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a link in future. Thanks.

Comment: @icedwater - I added my code here directly next to the Bootply link I already supplied. Is that OK now? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'have updated your css.

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.carousel-indicators li { visibility: hidden; }

.carousel-inner .item {
    font-size:10px;
    color:#0404B4
    }

.carousel-control {
    z-index: 10;
    top: 2%;
    width: 30px; // no more gray thing
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right { background: none }
// change it according to your needs
.carousel-control.left { left: -10px; }
.carousel-control.right { right: -10px; }
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/FMjJfm6hTt)